# How to Solve non-specific non-linear equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, idl

I am attempting to fit a circle to some data. This requires numerically solving a set of three non-linear simultaneous equations (see the Full Least Squares Method of  [this document](http://www.cs.bsu.edu/homepages/kerryj/kjones/circles.pdf)).

To me it seems that the `NEWTON` function provided by IDL is fit for solving this problem. `NEWTON` requires the name of a function that will compute the values of the equation system for particular values of the independent variables:

```
FUNCTION newtfunction,X
    RETURN, [Some function of X, Some other function of X]
END
```

While this works fine, it requires that all parameters of the equation system (in this case the set of data points) is hard coded in the `newtfunction`.  This is fine if there is only one data set to solve for, however I have many thousands of data sets, and defining a new function for each by hand is not an option.

Is there a way around this?  Is it possible to define functions programmatically in IDL, or even just pass in the data set in some other manner?

Comment: Typically in these cases you define a model function that takes a set of parameters and actual data points.  For instance, assume your function is Y = A*X + B.  Then the model function (in your case, newtfunction) will take an array of X values and then an array of parameter values, say, param = [A, B].  You then provide the fitting routine with the function name and initial guesses and then let it go.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Craig Markwardt's [webpage](http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/) which has several routines that are better than the Newton method (e.g., Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm).

Comment: Neither of these comments really address my question.  The newtfunction by definition is only allowed to take a single parameter. If have since found a different way to fit a circle to data, however that is the topic of a different question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this matter, but if I were to solve this problem I would do the following. Instead of solving a system of 3 non-linear equations to find the three unknowns (i.e. `xc`, `yc` and `r`), I would use an optimization routine to converge to a solution by starting with an initial guess. For this steepest descent, conjugate gradient, or any other multivariate optimization method can be used.

I just quickly derived the least square equation for your problem as (please check before use):

`F = (sum_{i=1}^{N} (xc^2 - 2 xi xc + xi^2 + yc^2 - 2 yi yc + yi^2 - r^2)^2)`

Calculating the gradient for this function is fairly easy, since it is just a summation, and therefore writing a steepest descent code would be trivial, to calculate `xc`, `yc` and `r`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's usual to use a `COMMON` block in these types of functions to pass in other parameters, cached values, etc. that are not part of the calling signature of the numeric routine.